# Showing / hiding same div class nested in different div's with javascript based on changing number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i'm trying to show/hide a div class based on what "page" is active (a number that changes). So i have a dynamic number of pages which are indicated by the publication.realpages.length and i have an equal number of main/sub/target divs. I'd like to show the target class at each seperate location depending what page we are o

so my html is always

```
 <div id="main">
    <div id="sub">
       <div class="target"></div>
   </div>
 </div>


  <div id="main2">
    <div id="sub2">
       <div class="target"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

my current javascript is

```
    publication.on('page', function(page) {
    var currpage = page.realIndex + 1
    var pubpage = publication.realPages.length
    if (currpage == 1) {
    (".target").show();
    };
   });
```

I've tried with `for( i = 0, i >= pubpage, i++);` but i don't grasp how i could make each target individually appear after that.

```
currpage = current active page
pubpage = total number of pages
```

I'm basically looking for a way to adress the same class but that has different parents. Also a way that i don't have to write currpage === 1, currpage === 2, etc for each page.

Comment: how are you relating the page and div?

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly. Assuming that you want the target div inside the current page to be shown then you can use this `$(".target").eq(currpage).show();`

Comment: If you mean by relating the page and div. Basically i'd like for currpage 1 to show the target class div that's nested in main div1. currpage 2 to show the target class div in main div2. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *currpage*, you might want to do it like this ([quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyhocofk/1/)):

```
var mainId = "#main" + currpage;
var subId = "#sub" + currpage;
var accessor = mainId + " " + subId + " .target";
$(accessor).show();
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I did not realize this was possible. I forgot to post in my question that if a diff. one is activated all others should be hidden but thank you so much.